# How to render my graph using QuickGraph C#

Tags: c#, render, directed-graph, quickgraph

I'm new to [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/). I followed the examples on the documentation page to add vertices & edges to my graph. 
Now, I want to display my graph on a windows form. I'm using Graphviz for that purpose, which generates a .DOT file as output. I'm following the code sample below for rendering:

```
IVertexAndEdgeListGraph<TVertex,TEdge> g= ...;
var graphviz = new GraphvizAlgorithm<TVertex,TEdge>(g);
string output = graphviz.Generate(new FileDotEngine(), "graph");
```

But, my compiler is not detecting `FileDotEngine()`. Moreover, I don't know what to do after the .DOT file is generated.

Comment: FYI the code in this question is just the example from https://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visualization%20Using%20Graphviz&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a `FileDotEngine` yourself; see for instance [this example on Github](https://github.com/serra/QuickgraphExamples/blob/master/src/examples/Support/Visualizer.cs#L55). A simple `FileDotEngine` that generates a jpg could be:

```
public sealed class FileDotEngine : IDotEngine
{
    public string Run(GraphvizImageType imageType, string dot, string outputFileName)
    {
        string output = outputFileName;
        File.WriteAllText(output, dot);

        // assumes dot.exe is on the path:
        var args = string.Format(@"{0} -Tjpg -O", output);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("dot.exe", args);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Then you could display the generated image in a picture box or similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your reply. However, my code is unable to find the file "dot.exe". I just searched for it & came to know that it's not on my system as well. What should I do now? Can I download it from some location?

Comment: dot.exe is part if the graphviz package - from your question I thought you already used it. Google for graphviz and windows and you'll find it in no time

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to host a WPF control in your winforms app and then use [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/) to display the graph. I haven't tried this myself, however.